SortableJs will reorder elements after get actual position from backend
how I can update current position element, after get this information from server? I have array with elements, and store method, but after render component I can't reorder elements in list, only manual method move elements.
I'm was try use store, but this don't help me.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I see what I did.

Sort the array the way we need it
Init SortableJS.

I originally initialized the library first and only then sorted the elements, so that didn't work.
